# How do I add a div with an animation to webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically trying to put a laser beam on the screen to shoot baddies. Like with Space Invaders or Galaga but I can't seem to get the laser to actually move when I click the button. This is what I have:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<button type='button'>click me</button>
<div id="laser" style="display: none; background-color:red; width:100px; height:50px"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('button').click(function()
{
    $('#container').append($('#laser'));
    $('#laser').show()
    $('#laser').animate({left:'500px'},5000);
});
)};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2S8k/363/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute;left:0` to `#laser` and move the script to the bottom so the eventListener gets added when the button exists.

http://jsfiddle.net/8KA59/1/

Comment: why do I have to add the position:absolute;left:0 and move the script down?

Comment: Does it try to execute the script before the button is actually created or something?

Comment: Because we need an initial value for `left` for it to animate, and also `left` only works when the `position` is `absolute`,`fixed` or `relative`

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: You really don't need to explicitly set an initial value for `left`. The animation runs from whatever is the current `left` value (even if it is `auto`) to 500px.

Comment: The code for your answer should be in the answer itself; having to check the JSFiddle for the answer is against our standards for answering a question.  If JSFiddle goes down we can't see the answer.

Comment: You do not have to check the fiddle for the answer, its just for a demo.